# Adding onclose method in magnificPopup (that autoloads on pageload)

Tags: magnific-popup

We have [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K9Geq/1/) a good example of adding onclose functions for [magnificPopup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api).

However, this works when we call magnificPopup with an onclick event. I was wondering how to add onclose functions when magnificPopup autoloads on pageload.

Here is the code:

```
<?
if (is_array($flashMessage) && count($flashMessage) > 0) {
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
          src: '#confirmation',
          type:'inline'
      }
    });
});
</script>
<? } ?>
```

On this, I need to add onclose event with window.location. Thanks for any help.

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same?

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
items : {
    src: '#test-popup',
},
type: 'inline',
    callbacks: {
        open: function () {
            $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function () {
                var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure?"+window.location.href);
                if (!confirmed) {
                    return;
                }
                $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

I guess You had problems with `type:'inline'` in `items` object. Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9Geq/49/)